# Calculate rolling cross correlation with pandas (not Pearson)

Tags: python, matrix, correlation, cross-correlation

I would like to implement a rolling estimate of correlation between two series. However, I do not want a normalized output (Pearson, Spearman or other), but the output should provide values given by the numpy.correlate function.

The df.rolling().corr() function gives the Pearson correlation.

Any suggestions?

**Edit to add sample data and expected output**

As a toy example with a window size of 2, use the following data and output.

```
a=pd.Series([1,3,4,1,3])
b=pd.Series([7,2,3,4,9])

c=a.copy()
c.iloc[0]=np.nan
for i in range(1,len(c)):
    c.iloc[i]=np.correlate(a.loc[i-1:i],b.loc[i-1:i])
```

```
 print(c)
0     NaN
1    13.0
2    18.0
3    16.0
4    31.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think that you can use a custom function with [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) after `rolling`. If you provide a some sample data to work with, I can give it a shot.